# Unable to getChild() from XML object

Tags: xml, google-apps-script

I try to get a child from an Element in a XML context in Google Apps Script.
The XML Element looks like this:

```
<wsKlasgroep>
<p_persoon>39579</p_persoon>
...
</wsKlasgroep>
```

So I try to get the p_persoon text object using:

```
indiviual_class.getChild("p_persoon")
```

Which results in a null. So I tried to loop all children, showing all the names and values:

```
let classes = xmlResult.getChildren();
classes.forEach(indiviual_class => {
   Logger.log(indiviual_class.getChild("p_persoon"));        //null
   indiviual_class.getChildren().forEach(child => {
        Logger.log(child.getName() + ": " + child.getText());//p_persoon: 39579
      });
    });
```

Why can't I access a Child by it's name, while the data seems to be right? I'm clearly missing something here.

Thanks for any help

Comment: By guessing your situation, I proposed 2 answers. Could you please confirm it? If those were not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Hi, sorry I was asleep in Europe. Your answer was indeed correct, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of `<wsKlasgroep><p_persoon>39579</p_persoon>...</wsKlasgroep>` you show, the root is `<wsKlasgroep>`. If `xmlResult` is the root, the length of `indiviual_class.getChildren()` is `0`. From this situation, I thought that in your situation, the sample XML might be `<sample><wsKlasgroep><p_persoon>39579</p_persoon></wsKlasgroep></sample>`. But, unfortunately, I cannot know your actual XML data. So, in this answer, from your showing script and your showing XML, I would like to propose an answer.

#### Answer 1:

In this answer, `const xml = "<wsKlasgroep><p_persoon>39579</p_persoon></wsKlasgroep>";` is used. And the value of `39579` is retrieved.

```js
function sample1() {
  const xml = "<wsKlasgroep><p_persoon>39579</p_persoon></wsKlasgroep>";
  const root = XmlService.parse(xml).getRootElement();
  const value = root.getChild("p_persoon", root.getNamespace()).getValue();
  console.log(value)
}
```

When this script is run, you can see `39579` in the log.

#### Answer 2:

In this answer, `const xml = "<sample><wsKlasgroep><p_persoon>39579</p_persoon></wsKlasgroep></sample>";` is used. And the value of `39579` is retrieved.

In this sample, `getChildren()` is used as you are using in your showing script.

```js
function sample2() {
  const xml = "<sample><wsKlasgroep><p_persoon>39579</p_persoon></wsKlasgroep></sample>";
  const root = XmlService.parse(xml).getRootElement();
  const ns = root.getNamespace();
  root.getChildren().forEach(indiviual_class => {
    const value = indiviual_class.getChild("p_persoon", ns).getValue();
    console.log(value)
  });
}
```

In this sample, `getChildren()` is not used.

```js
function sample3() {
  const xml = "<sample><wsKlasgroep><p_persoon>39579</p_persoon></wsKlasgroep></sample>";
  const root = XmlService.parse(xml).getRootElement();
  const ns = root.getNamespace();
  const value = root.getChild("wsKlasgroep", ns).getChild("p_persoon", ns).getValue();
  console.log(value)
}
```

When this script is run, you can see `39579` in the log.

#### Note:

- In this case,  `root.getNamespace()` is used as the namespace. But, unfortunately, I cannot know your actual XML data and your whole script. So, if the above modifications were not useful, can you provide more sample XML and script? By this, I would like to confirm your actual situation.

#### Reference:

- [XML Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service)

Comment: Thanks, it was indeed the namespace I was missing. In my example I used const p_persoonValue = indiviual_class.getChild("p_persoon", indiviual_class.getNamespace()).getValue(); when looping over the 'classes' and it works.

Comment: @Mathias Maes Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.